# Prove that $\frac{3}{4}<\int_{0}^{1} x^x dx <\frac{85}{108}.$

Tags: definite-integrals

Let $I=\int_{0}^{1} x^x dx$, the function $f(x)=x^x$ attains a local minimum at $x=e^{-1}$ and $f''(x)>0, \forall x\in (0, \infty).$ So $f(x)>e^{-e^{-1}}\approx 0.69.$ Next, one may choose a point $x=1/2$, the chords in $x \in (0,1/2)$ and in $x \in (1/2,1)$ lie above the curve $y=f(x)$ due to its positive definite curvature. So, $I$ will be less than the area under these two identical trapeziums, we get $I<\frac{2+\sqrt{2}} {4}\approx 0.85,$ whereas $I=0.787....$ Hoever, in the process of finding better bounds on $I$, I found that 
$$\frac{3}{4}<\int_{0}^{1} x^x dx <\frac{85}{108}.$$
I hope that you will find it interesting to prove this result.

Comment: What is the question ? It seems more like a proposed exercise, but that's not the point of posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream) we have
$$
I = \int_{0}^{1} x^x dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}n^{-n} = 1 - \frac{1}{2^2} +\frac{1}{3^3} - \frac{1}{4^4} +- \ldots \, .
$$
That is an alternating series and the absolute values of the elements are decreasing, so that the value of the series lies between consecutive partial sums.

In particular,
$$
\underbrace{1 - \frac{1}{2^2}}_{3/4}  < I < \underbrace{1 - \frac{1}{2^2} +\frac{1}{3^3}}_{85/108}
$$

---

One can also mimic the proof of Sophomore's dream: For $0 < x < 1$ is
$$
 x^x = e^{x \log x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x \log x)^n}{n!}
$$
an alternating series  whose absolute values are decreasing, so that
$$
 1 + x \log x < x^x < 1 + x \log x + \frac 12 (x \log x)^2
$$
Integrating these inequalities gives the desired estimate.